# How do I specify how often to poll?

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash

I'm working with [Logstash's Kafka input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html) and I don't see any setting which would allow me to specify how often should the consumer poll.

If I check the [consumer configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#newconsumerconfigs) I don't see anything either there.

How does it work then?
How does the consumer know when to try to pull data in?

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of configurables on that one, [but `poll_timeout_ms` seems to be the one controlling the poll interval](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html#plugins-inputs-kafka-poll_timeout_ms). It defaults to 100ms. The Kafka plugin maintains an open TCP connection to the Kafka cluster, so you don't get connection-establishment overhead for a fast polling interval.